# report_activate_error when setup windows service for mongrel

Tags: redmine, mongrel

I try to install Redmine using this step: http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Install_Redmine_in_a_sub-URI_on_Windows_with_Apache

Works fine with some error than can be solved after searching on Google

But then, when on step Setup windows services(http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Install_Redmine_in_a_sub-URI_on_Windows_with_Apache#Setup-windows-services), I get this error message:

```
D:\xampp\rubyapp\redmine-1.3.0>mongrel_rails service::install -N mongrel_redmine_3001 -D "Mongrel serving Redmine on 3001" -p 3001 -e production -c D:
\xampp\rubyapp\redmine-1.3.0
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:900:in `report_activate_error': RubyGem version error: win32-service(0.5.2 not < 0.6.0, >= 0.5.2) (Gem::
LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:248:in `activate'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1276:in `gem'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel_service-0.3.4-x86-mswin32/lib/mongrel_service/init.rb:37:in `validate'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mingw32/bin/../lib/mongrel/command.rb:208:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mingw32/bin/mongrel_rails:281
        from C:/Ruby187/bin/mongrel_rails:19:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby187/bin/mongrel_rails:19
```

For information about my instalation:

Gem list:

```
D:\xampp\rubyapp\redmine-1.3.0>gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (2.3.5)
actionpack (2.3.5)
activerecord (2.3.5)
activeresource (2.3.5)
activesupport (2.3.5)
cgi_multipart_eof_fix (2.5.0)
gem_plugin (0.2.3)
i18n (0.4.2)
mongrel (1.1.5 x86-mingw32)
mongrel_service (0.3.4 i386-mswin32)
mysql (2.8.1 x86-mingw32)
rack (1.1.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.0)
rails (2.3.5)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rdoc (2.4.2)
rubygems-update (1.6.2)
win32-service (0.5.2 mswin32)

D:\xampp\rubyapp\redmine-1.3.0>mongrel_rails --version
Mongrel Web Server 1.1.5

D:\xampp\rubyapp\redmine-1.3.0>ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-12-28 patchlevel 357) [i386-mingw32]
```

How to solved this error ? I don't have any idea what to do

Answer (score 2):

- Uninstall mongrel_service and win32-service gems (gem unistall )
- run "gem install mongrel_service" command. At this time this will install mongrel_service 0.4.0 instead of 0.3.4 which is installed per the guide. It seem to work and does not seem to depend on win32-service at all. YMMV.